# How to remove jank from overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal that changes my body to `overflow:hidden` when clicked. This removes the scrollbar so my page wont scroll. When you close the modal, my body changes back to `overflow:auto` and the page can scroll again. This is done with two simple functions I set in my Javascript.

```
function hidden() {
    document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function show() {
    document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

However, there's some jank involved where you can see my entire page move to the right when the scrollbar is removed. Is there any way I can fix this to not look so bad? Or perhaps there's a different way to disable scrolling when the modal is up?

Comment: have you tried `position.fixed` for the body instead of `overflow.hidden`? It might not have jank. (restoring scroll could use `position.relative`

Comment: @Bman70 I have actually. `position.fixed` makes my entire page left aligned for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable scrolling while keeping the scrollbar with a JS event listener to intercept scroll events like this:

```js
const ignoreScroll = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
};

// Add scrolling block
document.addEventListener('scroll', ignoreScroll);
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', ignoreScroll);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', ignoreScroll);

// Remove scrolling block
document.removeEventListener('scroll', ignoreScroll);
document.removeEventListener('mousewheel', ignoreScroll);
document.removeEventListener('touchmove', ignoreScroll);
```

You could also programmatically apply the `touch-action: none` CSS rule to disable scrolling on an element.

Comment: Can you go into detail how I'd use this? I'm still fairly new to JS so I don't fully understand. I see that you wrote a function and added some eventListeners. Are the eventListeners executing the function you wrote? Would these just replace where I had my original functions executing? Thank you.

Comment: @Dylan You would add the event listeners inside your show function, and remove them in your hide function. The event listeners execute the function you provide it whenever the event defined in the first argument is fired. ignoreScroll just takes the event and prevents the default behavior (scrolling).

Comment: I'm trying just that but it doesn't seem to be working for me like the overflow trick did.

Comment: @Dylan Could you create a codepen for me to take a look?